# Seaching for a file inside a main folder

Tags: perl, unix, find

I have a main result folder inside which there are multiple *config.txt* files.
However, i need to get the paths of only the *config.txt* files inside the *netlist* sub-folder, inside the main result folder, which is given.

I have tried this code, but it didn't work out.

```
find $mainResultPath -name "config.txt"
```

Here is a snippet of the code assuming we are already in the *$mainResultPath*
[Code snippet and reqd files ticked](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dq7YFUeNxxpbkrimGbvL9WLAGV9pgjsR)

Comment: find $mainResultPath -name "netlist/config.txt" DOESNT WORK ALSO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
find $mainResultPath -type d -name netlist | \
   xargs -I {} find {} -maxdepth 1 -type f -name config.txt
```

i.e. first filter out the `netlist` directories and then search in those for `config.txt` files.

Example output from my test:

```
$ find $HOME/Documents -type f -name config.txt
/home/.../Documents/Downloads/RFC/netlist/config.txt
/home/.../Documents/config.txt
/home/.../Documents/netlist/config.txt

$ find $HOME/Documents -type d -name netlist
/home/.../Documents/Downloads/RFC/netlist
/home/.../Documents/Downloads/netlist
/home/.../Documents/netlist

$ find $HOME/Documents -type d -name netlist | xargs -I {} find {} -maxdepth 1 -name config.txt
/home/.../Documents/Downloads/RFC/netlist/config.txt
/home/.../Documents/netlist/config.txt
```

**EDIT 2:** If you don't like the 2nd find, then this works too

```
$ find $HOME/Documents -type d -name netlist | \
     while read _d; do [ -f "${_d}/config.txt" ] && echo "${_d}/config.txt"; done
```

Comment: just what i needed. Thanks!